# Automorphism of the function field and birational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective complex manifold and $\mathbb{C}(X)$ its function field i.e. field consisting of meromorphic functions on $X$. Is it true that any $\phi\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C}(X))$ induces a birational map $\tilde{\phi} \in \mathrm{Bir}(X)$? i.e. $\phi=\tilde{\phi}^*$. I am aware that the converse is always true. If the above assertion is true, how can one prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you already know that $X$ is algebraic, this is an easy exercise. It is also included in any introduction to algebraic geometry, for example Hartshorne, Chapter I, Theorem 4.4.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the reference, Martin.